# Dynamical update a textfield on live events

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

i am at the moment developing a Softphone with javafx. and i kind of a have problem capturing incoming call to a textfield. an example of my code is here.
an incoming call is with Joptionpane successful bt i had like to have the value appear in call textfield just like telephone.
Thank you.

```
public void telephoneNumbs(String numbers) {
    String replace = numbers.replace("sip:", "").trim().replace(".", ""); // Incoming Call Numbers from Sip UA
    if (!replace.isEmpty()) {
       List<TelephoneObj> telephons; 
        telTextField.setText(null); //init it with null
         costumDao = new CostumersDao(); // costumers DB 
         telephons = costumDao.getOrCompareTelfone(numbers);
           for (TelephoneObj tmp : telephons) {
               System.out.println("Test: " + tmp.getTelephoneNums); // am getting exactle what i need here from my Database
               //or 
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"incoming:"+ tmp.getTelephoneNums); // it show it during incoming calls

               //here is the problem. it wouldnt show the Value on the Textfield
                telTextField.setText(tmp.getTelephoneNums); //try to push that Value(Telephone number) to show in JFXTextfield/it cold be any other Textfields

           }


    }
```

Comment: where is your textfield related code?

Comment: You're doing something wrong. It's not possible to provide you with any info about your exact issue, since you didn't post the info required to identify the issue. Create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sooo much happy today it went well with after 2days of thinking how to solve this miserable life of not taking time to think.
I finally got the answer by using Task to solve the problem.

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        {
            updateMessage("");
        }

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {

            while (true) {
                updateMessage(callee);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    };

    //neuLabel.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    kdAddrTel.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);

    th.start();
```

Comment: This wasn't needed. but helped me get a way or to understand how the code should have been. but problem was solved.